# Read environment variable set by child process in c#

Tags: c#

I just launched a new process from my code. This new process calls a command program that sets few variables and runs its program.

Is there a way i can get the values of variables the child program is setting?

Thanks

Comment: Parents don't inherit environment variables from children, so this is at best non-trivial.

Comment: What are these variables used for?  Does the "parent" code need to be notified when these variables are available or can it do some kind of polling?

Comment: Do you not have access to the command program? Is it a script?

Comment: @Pete: These variables are used to for the child program to execute. Its basically setting up some environment for the applicaiton to use.

Comment: @Bill: Can you clarify on access to command program?? Its a command line program.

Comment: I understand that much...  What does the parent program need them for?  I'm driving at whether it's worth setting up a service endpoint in the parent program to be called by the child program, or if you can do something simpler like writing to a text file/db/what-have-you.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the environment variable with [ProcessStartInfo.EnvironmentVariables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.environmentvariables.aspx) so if you can find a way to get those ahead of time, you won't need to share the environments.

I'm not at an IDE so I cannot confirm but you *might* be able to use that method after the fact (though I doubt it).

You could also have the parent process be a batch script and parse the output.

```
master.exe
set
```